# How can I create refresh button in Flutter(web developing)?

Tags: flutter, refresh

I need to create refresh button in flutter(like in the other browsers). But I can't find any info about it.
Please help me. Here is the code

```
IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: _refreshAction,
              tooltip: 'Refresh'
            ),

_refreshAction() {
  setState(() {
    _response = http.read(dadJokeApi, headers: httpHeaders);
  });
}
```

I can’t understand why the error comes out

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Move '_refreshAction()' to somewhere else in the entire code. Or `onPressed: _refreshAction` change `onPressed: () {setState(() { _response = http.read(dadJokeApi, headers: httpHeaders); });}`